# Why aren't Umbraco Templates (Views) part of the Solution/Project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I typically work on ASP.NET Core MVC projects, but am currently working on an Umbraco site. A difference I noticed, and don't understand, is that the `.cshtml` files in the `Views` folder (which are the Umbraco Templates) are only visible in the Folder View of the Solution Explorer. Why aren't they included in the project and visible in the normal Solution Explorer view like they are in a normal MVC project?

Example:

Folder View:

[image]

Normal Solution Explorer View:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's typically because no one added them ;-) Joking aside, views can also be created via the Umbraco back office (in the browser) in which case the VS project doesn't really know about them until they are included.

Comment: Yes - those are the Views I'm referring to. So I'm wondering if there is any particular reason that the views aren't included in the project when views are created in the back office. Is it just that it's not possible to add a file to a project via code at runtime? I get the sense from your answer that it doesn't cause any *problems* to include them in the project, right?

Comment: Yeah, Umbraco doesn't try to change your project file (as it may not exist). Should be totally safe to add them, I always do and have had no issues :-)

Comment: Are there any files for which it's not safe to add them? Or can I just add all the files in the Project directory to the project?

Comment: You could probably add everything. App_data shouldn't ever be deployed though, so you might want to not include anything from that folder.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is because whatever is not included in your project, will not be released when you deploy through Visual Studio.

In a scenario where Continuous Integration exists and there are one click deployments going on with 'release' configurations (aka live environment configurations), when you right click on the project and click 'Publish' anything that's not included will be ignored from the release. That goes for models, Views, controllers, you name it.

It basically helps with big projects that have older views that you no longer needed (but for some reason the code should remain there).